# How to officially keep a track record of Faction Journal Card goals completion in Pathfinder Society?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-sheets, pathfinder-society, organized-play

Faction Journal Cards represent a long way of getting some favors with your chosen faction through accomplishing secondary objectives related to the Faction's interests during missions. These favors give some circumstantially substantial mechanical benefits, so one could think that these should be verified in a way similar to how, for example, the experience or gold gain are verified.

Can't find any rules on how to legalize the checked boxes preceding the goals. How to specify that specific task was indeed completed on a specific adventure?

- Should it be written into a Chronicle sheet the task was accomplished in?
- Should it be verified on a Faction Journal Card by a GM?

Neither really have the layout, or sometimes space, for that.

- Should the Journal Card be accepted as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [Faction Card Forum](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5lhcl&page=3?Faction-Journal-Cards), Global Organized Play Coordinator Michael Brock indicates **no GM certification is required, they are using the honor system for a change.**

User Blackfoot (Apr 14, 2015 8:18am):

> A player can't have more boxes checked than they have XP/Scenarios/Chronicles... but otherwise the checks don't reference where they came from in any way. Is the GM really involved in any way with keeping track of these things?

GOPC Brock (Apr 14, 2015 11:50am):

> if someone wants to cheat, they will cheat. It's life and it happens. If we put lines for a GM to initial, the person could just initial it himself and no one would be the wiser. The next GM won't know if it is an actual GM's initials or not. We are trying to go with the belief that the majority of people will just play nice and use these in the spirit they have been presented - another way to try to immerse the character into the world through accomplishing goals for their faction.